# Sencha Touch MVC issues: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ superclass.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'setActiveItem'

Tags: sencha-touch

I've got a list view that extends panel, and I define a listener for an `itemtap` event that does an `Ext.dispatch` to my controller, that I basically want to set my form view as active. In my controller's action, the method looks like this:

```
itemTap : function(dataObj) {
    var views = dataObj.views,
    contactForm = views.contactForm,
    model = dataObj.model;
    console.log(dataObj);

    contactForm.loadRecord(model);

    this.application.Viewport.setActiveItem(contactForm, {type:'slide', direction:'right'});
}
```

I get an error on my last line of this action: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ superclass.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'setActiveItem'` and I'm having a hard time deciphering this error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `this.application.Viewport` a function? (It looks like it is.)

Comment: @Matt it's referring to the namespace that was created when registering the Viewport class.

Comment: @Matt, you put me on the right track to the answer. I needed to replace the offending line with: `MyApp.viewport.setActiveItem(contactForm, {type:'slide', direction:'right'});` (lowercase "v")

Comment: Hey Buffalo, If you solved you problem I guess you can close the question right?
One tip: move your business logic into controllers and dispatch to that. That way the views remain only responsible for the graphical part. If your application starts growing you will cause yourself maintainability headaches otherwise.
Good luck